# How to disable preview images in Google Chrome Omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

With a recent update, the URL bar in Chrome has started to show images for suggestions it thinks are relevant:

[image: Sample image of suggestions with one suggestion having an image next to it]

How do I turn this feature off?
I've already disabled `#omnibox-rich-entity-suggestions`, `#omnibox-pedal-suggestions` and `#omnibox-local-entity-suggestions` in `chrome://flags`.

Answer (score 1):

What stopped it for me was disabling in addition
`chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-show-suggestion-favicons`.

However, this replaced all favicons by generic watch icons
(the same as besides the above "hop - Google Search").

Comment: I toggled that flag to disabled as well, but sadly the issue persists. Could it be you've used some additional flag?

Comment: No other flags but `#omnibox-rich-entity-suggestions`, which all sources claim should be enough. Perhaps uninstalling Chrome (saving bookmarks), scrubbing all folders and reinstall would help.

Answer (score 0):

only workaround to this bug is to change the default search engine for

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s
```